# CallContext.LogicalGetData() vs ThreadLocal/ThreadStatic

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, thread-local

I am currently using `Threadlocal` for holding the current user's id to use throughout the app per each user's web request. I don't have access to the `HttpContext` in lower environments, but want to access a static UserId without passing it as a parameter everywhere. 
Recently, I've been adding parallel operations via `async/await.` This no longer can guarantee I have the proper value in each `Task.`

I research and discovered `AsyncLocal` in `.Net 4.6`, but am currently limited to `.Net 4.5.1`. As an alternative, is `CallContext.LogicalGet/SetData()` able to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Better pass that parameter. You're over complicating your design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the logical call context will work as an async-local.

`AsyncLocal<T>` uses the logical call context on the full .NET framework - it just has a nicer API and will work with the upcoming .NET Core platform while the logical call context will not.

Remember to [only store immutable data](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html), as I describe on my blog.

Also, there is a definite performance impact with async-local values. It would almost definitely be more performant to pass the parameter explicitly, perhaps as part of your own `RequestContext` type. ASP.NET vCore is moving away from `HttpContext.Current`; it still has the concept of `HttpContext`, but it doesn't act as an async local anymore - it's passed explicitly.

Comment: @Maxim: Are you sure? I doubt `AsyncLocal<T>` would be 5 times slower than `CallContext.Logical*`.

Comment: I tested it yesterday with 20 jobs (Parallel.ForEach).. run on 10 threads (experimentally detected by thread ids)...  each job has "for" loop with 10 millions iterations, each loop iteration gets AsyncLocal / CallContext value and sets incremented value back. Results are 50 and 10 seconds for AsyncLocal / CallContext (approximately).

Comment: @Maxim: A 4-microsecond difference usually doesn't matter. There's also a lot of problems inherent in measuring timings this small.

Comment: There are no any problems to measure time. I used total time from start to end of whole process (simulation of multi-threaded work with 100% CPU load). So it is comparable to performance difference of different IoC containers...

Comment: @StephenCleary I can confirm that it's much slower, it also generates A LOT of memory traffic.